# concatenating the content of list in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list.

```
list = ['It is a delightfully naive and entertaining movie',
        'The songs are boring and dated in 2009',
        'was a great movie from genre director Luc Besson']
```

and I want a result like:

```
list_result = [ It is a delightfully naive and entertaining movie The songs are boring and dated in 2009 was a great movie from genre director Luc Besson]
```

how I can do this? (list_result can also be a corpus.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = ""
for sentence in list:
    result += sentence
    result += " "
list_result = [result]
```

Go over list comprehension if you want a more pythonic way to do it, here is the most understandable to begin.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this question isn't suitable for Datascience, go over to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) for these kind of questions.

Secondly, I advice you to look up some introductory tutorials for Python. The Python wiki has a whole list of these [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers).

Lastly, as to answer your question:

```
l = ['AB', 'CD', 'EF']
o = ' '.join(l)
```

output:

```
>>> o
'AB CD EF'
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following DF:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
                                                 txt
0  It is a delightfully naive and entertaining movie
1             The songs are boring and dated in 2009
2   was a great movie from genre director Luc Besson
```

Use [Series.str.cat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
In [12]: df['txt'].str.cat(sep=' ')
Out[12]: 'It is a delightfully naive and entertaining movie The songs are boring and dated in 2009 was a great movie from genre director Luc Besson'
```